# Display image from FTP in Android Webview

Tags: android, image, ftp, webview

I am showing a page in **WebView** that has single image with

`<img src="ftp://.../image.gif" />`.

Note that the image is stored on **FTP server**.

The image shows as a question mark in the WebView.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added INTERNET permission on the Manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Yes. The problem is that Android WebView does not support FTP resources.